# ansible-playbook when conditions on uri module

Tags: ansible

I have ansbile playbook code :

```
- name: Send file to server
  uri:
    url: "{{ url }}:{{ port }}/application/{{ item | basename }}"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ lookup('file','{{ item }}') }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
    body_format: json
  with_fileglob: "{{ tmp_dir)_for_files }}/configs/*"
  register: code_result
  until: code_result.status == 201
  retries: "{{ uri_retries }}"
  delay: "{{ uri_delays }}"
```

What I need to achieve is that file will be uploaded to the sever only if the is not already there.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and whats not working as intended.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, because I do not have an idea how to do it

Comment: What is the error on the code above? Why isn't it working as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach  to this problem

```
- name: Get file from server
  uri:
    url: "{{ url }}:{{ port }}/application/{{ item | basename }}"
    method: GET
    body: "{{ lookup('file','{{ item }}') }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 404
    body_format: json
  with_fileglob: "{{ tmp_dir }}/configs/*"
  register: get_code_result
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Send file to server
  uri:
    url: "{{ url }}:{{ port }}/application/{{ item.item | basename }}"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ lookup('file','{{ item.item }}') }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
    body_format: json
  with_items:
      - "{{  get_code_result.results }}"
  when: item.status == 404
  register: code_result
  until: code_result.status == 201
  retries: "{{ uri_retries }}"
  delay: "{{ uri_delays }}"
```

It appears to be working